# Epson LQ590II ESC/P2 font pitch selection

Tags: printer, dot-matrix-printer

This printer supports 10/12/15/17 and 20 cpi via the control panel buttons. I need to be able to set it programmatically, however the latest Epson ESC/P 2 manual I can find only lists a command to set it to 15 cpi maximum, that being [ESC] g

Are there ESC/P 2 commands for 17 cpi and 20 cpi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found some old code related to set Epson printer cpi to 17 and 20, you may try.

17 cpi is char(27), char(80), char(15)
20 cpi is char(27), char(77), char(15)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that 17cpi is actually 10cpi with condensed mode printing enabled.